# A bankrupt man, a condemned man, and a lucky man

Tags: riddle

> A man leads his dog along a road until he reaches a friend's house. Suddenly he realizes he is bankrupt and takes his dog off the road.
> Another man wearing a hat stops at the street corner. He is extremely unhappy when he is suddenly arrested and taken to the jail the other side of town.
> A man visiting the condemned man in jail drives his car away from the jail until he finds a parking slot at the corner. He parks and is happy to find he is now very rich

Explain.

Comment: Parking at that parking space doesn't give you money.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole House rules in which it does are _very_ common.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole, usually any cards like chance where you lose money, or say you land on a tax square, the money goes under the free parking

Comment: Fake rules like those are why people think they don't like Monopoly.  Play the real game, not your made up version.

Comment: @thumbtackthief sorry I don't understand. (And I love monopoly, which is why I made a puzzle about it in the first place)

Comment: I mean, first off, this is not an original puzzle, but whatever.  The house rules you are suggesting are not real rules, and they make the game take hours and then everyone complains that the game is no fun and takes too long.  If you and your friends enjoy playing it that way, knock yourselves out--but it's not the real Monopoly, it's your own variant.

Comment: @thumbtackthief you are from the us which i know has a different version. I'm english and for us these are the real rules

Comment: No, they're not.  Look it up when you get home.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I've played the game a hundred times and these are the rules that I, and everyone I know use. So id be happy if you could just drop your argument, as I know these are the rules. If you disagree then ok I accept that but I'm not going to change the puzzle

Comment: That's a foolish argument.  Just because you all play by your own house rules doesn't make them right.  "Free parking
If you land on this space, you simply rest here until your next turn.
There is no penalty for landing here: you may still undertake
transactions as usual (for example, collect rent, build on Sites you
own, etc.)."  http://www.tmk.edu.ee/~creature/monopoly/download/official_rules_gathering/instructions.pdf

Comment: And you don't need to change the puzzle.  It's as good as it ever was on the countless other riddle books and websites I've seen it on.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I made this up, it's not plagiarised thank you

Comment: Ha, OK.  https://www.google.com/search?q=monopoly+puzzle+riddle&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS713US713&oq=monopo&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.1147j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @thumbtackthief yes and that is different isn't it?

Comment: Not even a little.  Best of luck.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'd be interested in seeing a copy of official rules that include money from free parking.  This is a house rule I played with when I was growing up but when I actually read the rules it wasn't in there, [page 4 here](http://www.tmk.edu.ee/~creature/monopoly/download/official_rules_gathering/instructions.pdf).  Keeping more money in circulation does make the game much longer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The explanation is that this is:

> Monopoly

A man leads his dog along a road until he reaches a friend's house. Suddenly he realizes he is bankrupt and takes his dog of the road.

> The man was using the dog as his monopoly piece.  When he went bankrupt, he lost and removed the dog from the board.

Another man wearing a hat stops at the street corner. He is extremely unhappy when he is suddenly arrested and taken to the jail the other side of town.

> This man was using the hat piece. He landed on the "Go to jail" space, which is the corner opposite of jail.

A man visiting the condemned man in jail drives his car away from the jail until he finds a parking slot at the corner. He parks and is happy to find he is now very rich

> This man, playing as the car, landed on the "free parking" space on the corner next to jail.

Comment: Correct, thought this was a bit easy. Can you explain the story in terms of the game?